# What is the beverage Thor is about to drink near the end of Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

Towards the end of the movie, Thor is chilling out on the ship and is about to serve himself a drink, just before he was interrupted by Loki.

As can be seen in the following pictures, he picks up a bottle with an orange liquid and pours it in a green glass:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, the label on the bottle is not clear, so my question is:

**What is the beverage Thor is about to drink?**

Comment: Perhaps orange soda?

Comment: @Forral Citation needed... Also, the god of thunder doesn't drink kids' beverages :P

Comment: @Loki obviously it's orange soda mixed with everclear, a true Asgard beverage

Comment: Aftershave! Well, look at the bottle ...

Comment: He must have inherited Scrapper 142 alcoholism!

Answer (score -4):

It’s probably suppose to be Mead. Nectar of the gods.

https://www.mybeeline.co/en/p/what-is-mead-the-drink-of-the-gods

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up? This isn't an Asgardian ship. Don't forget that they swiped it from Sakaar

Comment: Mead isn't that color, and I've never seen it in a liqueur bottle like that. (For one thing, many meads are at least slightly carbonated.)

Comment: @Matha: Really? I've partaken of several different Irish and Scottish meads, none of them were carbonated!